# How can I prevent Magit-status command from grabbing the frame focus?

Tags: magit, frames, focus

when executing magit-status and quickly focus out emacs, after the magit buffer pops up, emacs grabs the focus back. This is quite inconvenient. Is there a way to prevent that focus changing?

The way to reproduce this issue:

1. `emacs -Q` and load magit.
2. using `magit-status` command to load a middle size git project (which takes 1-2 seconds).
3. in the meantime, quickly focus away from the Emacs frame, say clicking on a browser window.
4. when `magit-status` buffer pops up, it grabs the focus back (which is what I'm trying to avoid)

Env:

```
Archlinux
i3wm
Emacs 27.0.50
magit d9ae466377b30d544fcbf5c57af1a60b350931af
```

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the variable `magit-display-buffer-noselect`, it seems when it is the default value, the function `magit-display-buffer` tries to raise the frame. FWIW, I can't reproduce the issue on Mac.

Comment: @xuchunyang `magit-display-buffer-noselect` works! thank you.

Comment: Could one of you please turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `magit-display-buffer-noselect` to `t` to prevent `magit-display-buffer` from calling `select-window`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it has changed since the answer from March 2018, but setting `magit-display-buffer-noselect` didn’t work for me (i3 would still raise the Emacs window).

I found it necessary to configure Emacs like so:

```
;; By default, when e.g. M-x magit-status opens a new buffer, the frame is
;; raised, which focuses the X11 window in i3, thereby stealing focus.
;;
;; By setting inhibit-switch-frame to t, Emacs will not call raise-frame.
(add-to-list
 'display-buffer-alist
 '(".*" . (display-buffer-reuse-window
           . ((inhibit-switch-frame . t)))))
```